# Função gets() para valor float

Tags: c, console

Queria utilizar a função `gets()` para um valor `float`, ou uma função semelhante.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: Por definição a função gets lê uma string, portanto após a leitura da string você precisa fazer a conversão para float. Não deixe de considerar as observações já feitas sobre a segurança desta função.

Answer (score 7):

Primeiro, nunca deveria usar `gets()` para nada, é uma função problemática, não portável e considerada obsoleta. Essa é uma das muitas coisas que ensinam errado por aí.

A solução é usar a variação mais adequada da função [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf). Mesmo esta há controvérsias se deveria ser usada. Até pode usar se souber bem o que está fazendo, se for um problema onde ela caiba muito bem ou um problema muito simples. Caso contrário a solução é criar uma função personalizada ou usar a [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), que é adotada por padrão por muita gente.

De qualquer forma em códigos reais que não são protótipos ou exercícios as pessoas usam uma forma própria de entrada de dados muito mais sofisticada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: [`gets()` era *obsoleta e depreciada* na versao C99](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.26.9p2). [Deixou de estar descrita no C11 (12o ponto)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp6) (os compiladores podem incluir a funcao como extra).

Answer (score 5):

Nunca use a função `gets()` porque é impossível dizer com antecedência quantos caracteres serão lidos, e por isso, `gets()` continuará a armazenar os caracteres lidos além do fim do buffer, o que é extremamente perigoso.

Por esse motivo, a função `gets()` da biblioteca padrão `stdio.h` se tornou obsoleta desde a versão C99 da linguagem C.

A alternativa segura e dentro padrão é o uso das funções: `scanf()` e `fgets()` que permitem o controle de quantos caracteres serão lidos para dentro do buffer com antecedêcia.

Exemplo com `fgets()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_MAX_TAM   (32)

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char buf[ BUFFER_MAX_TAM + 1 ];
    float f;

    printf( "Entre com um valor float: " );

    fgets( buf, BUFFER_MAX_TAM, stdin );

    f = atof( buf );

    printf( "Valor float lido: %f", f );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Exemplo com `scanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    float f;

    printf( "Entre com um valor float: " );

    scanf( "%f", &f );

    printf( "Valor float lido: %f", f );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Para maior segurança deves **sempre** validar o valor devolvido pela maioria das funções com protótipo em `<stdio.h>`: `if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) /* erro */;` ou `if (scanf("%d%d%d", &one, &two, &three) != 3) /* erro */;`